# Unable to merge Unity 5 into our iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

We have a large and complicated application and we are looking to upgrade our 3d engine to Unity 5.0. But I am having trouble integrating Unity.

I been trying to follow these tutorials but constant errors keep poping up whatever I do. 
http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/09/08/sandbox-unity-app-in-existing-ios-app/
http://www.makethegame.net/unity/add-unity3d-to-native-ios-app-with-unity-5-and-vuforia-4-x/
http://www.markuszancolo.at/2014/05/integrating-unity-into-a-native-ios-app/

If I just add the "Libraries" and the "Classes" folders into my project, I get an odd amount errors. It gets confused with other c code in the project(really doesn't like msgpack) and tries to import the wrong files (ILCPP files). If I remove all offending code from the project I still have a list of errors with the native cstring class.

> CompileC
>   /Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Intermediates/CricHQ.build/Debug-iphoneos/CricHQ.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-5D1DD4E92C87F57A.o
>   Classes/Other/main.mm normal armv7 objective-c++
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c++ -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation
>   -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wimplicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Warc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wexplicit-ownership-type -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wexit-time-destructors -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wassign-enum -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wstrict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wc++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk
>   -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -I/Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Intermediates/CricHQ.build/Debug-iphoneos/CricHQ.build/CricHQ\
>   Next.hmap
>   -I/Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -I/Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
>   -I/Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Classes
>   -I/Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/bdwgc/include
>   -I/Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include
>   -I/Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Classes/Native
>   -I/Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/CricEngine/source -I/Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Intermediates/CricHQ.build/Debug-iphoneos/CricHQ.build/DerivedSources/armv7
>   -I/Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Intermediates/CricHQ.build/Debug-iphoneos/CricHQ.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone -mno-thumb -DINIT_SCRIPTING_BACKEND=1 -include /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch
>   -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Intermediates/CricHQ.build/Debug-iphoneos/CricHQ.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-5D1DD4E92C87F57A.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Intermediates/CricHQ.build/Debug-iphoneos/CricHQ.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-5D1DD4E92C87F57A.dia
>   -c /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/main.mm -o /Users/jess/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CricHQ-bsrxghpplcwahnadlgmwxmzwbxff/Build/Intermediates/CricHQ.build/Debug-iphoneos/CricHQ.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-5D1DD4E92C87F57A.o
>
> In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:436:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:70:9:
>   error: no member named 'memcpy' in the global namespace; did you mean
>   'wmemcpy'? using ::memcpy;
>         ~~^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:435:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:152:10:
>   note: 'wmemcpy' declared here wchar_t *wmemcpy(wchar_t * __restrict,
>   const wchar_t * __restrict, size_t);
>            ^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:436:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:71:9:
>   error: no member named 'memmove' in the global namespace; did you mean
>   'wmemmove'? using ::memmove;
>         ~~^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:435:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:153:10:
>   note: 'wmemmove' declared here wchar_t *wmemmove(wchar_t *, const
>   wchar_t *, size_t);
>            ^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:436:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:72:9:
>   error: no member named 'strcpy' in the global namespace using
>   ::strcpy;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:73:9:
>   error: no member named 'strncpy' in the global namespace using
>   ::strncpy;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:74:9:
>   error: no member named 'strcat' in the global namespace using
>   ::strcat;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:75:9:
>   error: no member named 'strncat' in the global namespace using
>   ::strncat;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:76:9:
>   error: no member named 'memcmp' in the global namespace; did you mean
>   'wmemcmp'? using ::memcmp;
>         ~~^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:435:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:151:5:
>   note: 'wmemcmp' declared here int     wmemcmp(const wchar_t *, const
>   wchar_t *, size_t);
>           ^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:436:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:77:9:
>   error: no member named 'strcmp' in the global namespace using
>   ::strcmp;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:78:9:
>   error: no member named 'strncmp' in the global namespace using
>   ::strncmp;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:79:9:
>   error: no member named 'strcoll' in the global namespace; did you mean
>   'strtoll'? using ::strcoll;
>         ~~^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:13:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:44:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:169:3:
>   note: 'strtoll' declared here
>            strtoll(const char *, char **, int);
>            ^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:436:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:80:9:
>   error: no member named 'strxfrm' in the global namespace using
>   ::strxfrm;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:82:9:
>   error: no member named 'memchr' in the global namespace; did you mean
>   'wmemchr'? using ::memchr;
>         ~~^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:435:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/include/wchar.h:150:10:
>   note: 'wmemchr' declared here wchar_t *wmemchr(const wchar_t *,
>   wchar_t, size_t);
>            ^ In file included from :353: In file included from :4: In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Classes/Other/CricHQ_Prefix.pch:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:18:
>   In file included from
>   /Users/jess/Projects/GIT/CricHQ-iPhone/Libraries/../../CricHQ-3d/iOS-export/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/Locale.h:4:
>   In file included from
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:436:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:84:9:
>   error: no member named 'strchr' in the global namespace using
>   ::strchr;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:86:9:
>   error: no member named 'strcspn' in the global namespace using
>   ::strcspn;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:88:9:
>   error: no member named 'strpbrk' in the global namespace using
>   ::strpbrk;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:90:9:
>   error: no member named 'strrchr' in the global namespace using
>   ::strrchr;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:92:9:
>   error: no member named 'strspn' in the global namespace using
>   ::strspn;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:94:9:
>   error: no member named 'strstr' in the global namespace using
>   ::strstr;
>         ~~^ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:98:87:
>   error: no member named 'strchr' in the global namespace; did you mean
>   simply 'strchr'? inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY       char* strchr( 
>   char* __s, int __c) {return ::strchr(__s, __c);}
>                                                                                         ^~
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstring:98:46:
>   note: 'strchr' declared here inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
>   char* strchr(      char* __s, int __c) {return ::strchr(__s, __c);}

Screenshot:
[image: xcode errors]

Anyone know of a solution? Any help in this matter would be great as I'm totally stuck on what I should try next.

**Edit:** A plain project worked, so that is a start. Sounds like one of libraries is interfering maybe. The code base is large so need help narrowing the issue down.

**Edit 2:** Updated to Unity 5.1, xcode 7 beta, clean, deleted the DerivedData folder and still no change. 
Once I added "-ferror-limit=1000" then I saw 999+ errors instead of 30.

Common errors:

"Declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope".

"Call to 'X' is ambiguous" (cos, exp, ceil)

"Could not build module 'X'" (Foundation, Darwin)

"No member named 'X" in namespace" (memset, memcpy, memmove)

"Use of undeclared identifier 'x'" (strdup)

"Expected ';' after top level declarator"

**Edit 3:**
I solve the errors by setting "Always Search User Paths" to "No" in the XCode project settings.

But I'm having a few other issues.

Unity is still using CPU when I pause it. Is there anyway to solve this? I am calling Unity's "`applicationDidBecomeActive`" method. I also tried just calling "`UnityPause`".

Calling Unity's "GetAppController()" in my own code causes this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>
> "_GetAppController", referenced from:
>
> -[Test3d viewDidDisappear:] in Test3d.o 
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

Comment: If the images are too small to read, just right click on them and open in new tab. Or browser zoom in.

Comment: smells like Unity3D platform problem. Have you posted this in Unity3D section?

Comment: Yes I have. Not getting a lot of help from anywhere.

Comment: A plain project worked so it sounds like it is a library conflict issue.

Comment: I had a lot of bad experience when it comes to upgrading the Unity3D with a project that has out of source implementation, most of the problem actually got resolved by downgrading the Unity3D down a level. But if you don't have an original file that is a lower version of Unity3D you're pretty much stuck unless Unity3D works on this, or much worse. Force you to check the classes. 1 thing that comes into my mind about your problem is the ARM version. The ARM version is for Android actually there is an option that you can tweak it in the publish section of Android, I wonder what it is doing

Comment: in your Project, since I think you're working with iOS.

Comment: My project is using "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)" same as the Unity export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of my answers are in the question. The core solution was setting "Always Search User Paths" to "No" in the XCode project settings.

As for the last edit, I believe they are bugs. I don't use `GetAppController`, instead I have my own method. I have reported the CPU issue, it isn't a major problem as it is only ~3% on phones and ipads.

Answer (score 2):

I dont have enough reputation here to comment, so i write it as an answer:
After 3 Edits i am not sure what problems are still left...

GetAppController is an inline function in UnityAppController.h If it isnt linked to you project, you probably didnt include the file (but instead only declared GetAppController() somewhere yourself).

The other errors looks like you have conflicts with the basic c-libs. Is your other code using the c++ std lib? and if yes, which one? Which one is stated in Your BuildSettings under "C++ Standard Library"? It should be libc++

The "Solution" to switch "Always Search User Paths" to "No" sounds even more like a problem with other included projects.

Comment: "After 3 Edits i am not sure what problems are still left"
I would have removed the other edits but I kept them so others could solve their issues too. I also had a bounty so I didn't want to waste it by creating a new issue. 

I can call any method in UnityAppController.h but "GetAppController".
I might recreate the same method on my side for a work around.

"It should be libc++"
It is. 

"sounds even more like a problem with other included projects"
Maybe. I'll have to work with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem too recently trying to integrate my Unity 5 project into an existing iOS project. 
How I managed to integrate is

1) Drag `Class` and `Libraries` files from your `Unity` project into your iOS project. Same like the tutorial from the-nerd. Uncheck copy items, and select create group radio box.

2) Update your `Header Search Path` and `Library Search Path` under `Build Settings`. The folders should point to your `Unity` project folder.

Header Search Path -> Unity's Classes folder

Library Search Path -> Unity's Library folder

This part is really important, it made me solve those errors.

3) Under Build Phases, remember to create a run script and make sure the script points to the correct path in Unity's `Data` folder.

```
rm -rf "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Data"
cp -Rf "$PROJECT_DIR/../CHANGE THIS TO YOU PATH/Data" "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Data"
```

4) Compare the `Build Settings` from the Unity's project and your current iOS project. Make sure you select the correct C++ and C compiler. Your iOS project should match the one of Unity. Also the `Linker Flag` have to be in the correct order.

```
-weak_framework
CoreMotion
-weak-lSystem
```

That is all I did to make my iOS project compile with the Unity project I have. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yep that was what those tutorials basically said. I solved that issue. I added an edit, maybe you didn't notice, I asked for help on my new issues since this was never originally answered.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same. I still get the cstring error. I'm also following the-nerd tutorial. But I'm using unity 4.6 . are there differences between unity 4.6 and 5 in this matter? Thanks

Comment: You may want to export the project from Unity, and the try building it and running it directly from the exported project to see if it works on your device. If it does, the compilation should not be a problem. What you really need to do is compare the build settings of the exported unity iphone/ipad project with the project you want to merge with. The rest of the steps are the same as I have described above.